# Are recently accessed Realm objects kept in memory?

Tags: swift, realm

Suppose I fetch a list of Realm objects and access all the data from the results (causing the data to be loaded into memory). Next, with the reference to the list of objects still around, I fetch one of those objects directly by its primary key. Am I correct to assume that, in this case, the object will be returned without having to hit the disk? What if I no longer had a reference to that original list of results? Might it still be in memory?

Just curious to understand how objects are cached internally by Realm, so I don't unnecessarily try to optimize things in my code (e.g. holding onto objects that I think I'll use again soon) if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm memory-maps the file, and only accesses it when you actually read the properties on objects. This means that recent-accessed data will still be in memory until the OS has to discard it to free up that RAM for something else, and there is no difference in terms of disk i/o from obtaining a new object from Realm and holding on to an existing object.